# Custom FEST Assertions : Displaying readable message with

Tags: java, junit, testng, assertions, fest

I have created a custom FEST Condition to verify that my actual string either matches or is equal to an expected String

```
public class StringMatchesOrIsEqualTo extends Condition<String>{

    private String expectedStringOrExpression;

    public StringMatchesOrIsEqualTo(final String expectedStringorExpression){
        this.expectedStringOrExpression = expectedStringorExpression;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String value) {          
        return value.matches(expectedStringOrExpression) || value.equals(expectedStringOrExpression);
    }
}
```

Whenever the conditon fails i want it to display a message that shows me what the original and expected String was

currently the display string is

```
actual value:<'Some String'> should satisfy condition:<StringMatchesOrIsEqualTo>
```

is there a way that this message also displays what the match is made against ?

I tried overriding the toString method in the class

```
@Override
public String toString() {      
    return "string matches or is equal to : " + expectedStringOrExpression;
}
```

but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set the `description`, which can be done by calling the [`Condition(String)`](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-1.x/blob/def03985ff7cfb158754cbc4a7b8c7d5ce809f2d/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/Condition.java#L44) constructor:

```
public StringMatchesOrIsEqualTo(final String expectedStringorExpression){
    super("A String that matches, or is equal to, '" + expectedStringorExpression "'");
    this.expectedStringOrExpression = expectedStringorExpression;
}
```

Alternatively, you could override [`description()`](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-1.x/blob/def03985ff7cfb158754cbc4a7b8c7d5ce809f2d/src/main/java/org/fest/assertions/Condition.java#L71):

```
@Override
public String description()
{
    return "A String that matches, or is equal to, '" + expectedStringorExpression "'");
}
```